# Bootstrap grid not aligned properly when dynamically creating div

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to retrieve product information such as name,imagepath etc from database using repeater and display in the dataview using code behind. I could successfully retrieve and display the detail but the alignment of the div is not proper.

aspx code:

```
<div class="row">
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server"></asp:Repeater>
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img width="250px" height="300px" src="images/<%#Eval("ImagePath") %>" alt="<%#Eval("ProductName") %>">
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4><%#Eval("ProductName") %></h4>
                                    <h4><%#Eval("UnitPrice")%></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix">
                                </div>
                            </div>                                
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </div>
```

code behind:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ProductName, UnitPrice, ImagePath FROM Products", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.Sort = "ProductName"; // Sort by product name
        Repeater1.DataSource = dv;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
```

current output:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4DDQ.jpg)
Expected output:
The fourth image should come below the first image according to bootstrap gridview concept which is not happening in my case and because of which the entire layout changes.

I am a beginner and have just started to learn bootstrap.

Comment: This is because you have auto height of div. Please fix div height and it will solve your issue.

Comment: You can fix your div height or just add a <div class="clearfix"></div> once every 3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to resolve this issue:
1) End the row after 3 columns and start 2nd row for next 3 columns.
2) Add equal height for columns. You can use following script and add 'resize-height' class to each column.

```
function setHeight(column) {

        var maxHeight = 0;
        //Get all the element with class = col
        column = jQuery(column);
        column.css('height', 'auto');
        //Loop all the column
        column.each(function () {
            //Store the highest value
            if (jQuery(this).height() > maxHeight) {
                maxHeight = jQuery(this).height();
            }
        });
        //Set the height
        column.height(maxHeight);

}

jQuery(window).on('load resize', function () {
    setHeight('.resize-height');
});
```